# Integrate Keycloak IODC with Kubernetes Dashboard for SSO

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

Good day,

could you help me to fix a little issue with integration Keycloak SSO with Kubernetes Dashboard?

I’m trying to do the following steps:
Keycloak configurations:

- create a new Realm - Kubernetes
- create client ID with internal sing in, generate Client ID - Kubernetes
- create mapper group in Client
- created user and group

Keycloak-gatekeeper (Proxy):

- --discovery-url={{ .Values.keycloakProxy.serverHost }}
- --redirection-url=https://{{ .Values.ingress.host.name }}
- --upstream-url=https://{{ .Release.Name }}.{{ .Values.namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
- --client-secret={{ .Values.keycloakProxy.clientSecret }}
- --client-id=kubernetes
- --listen=0.0.0.0:3000
- --enable-refresh-tokens=false
- --skip-upstream-tls-verify
- --skip-openid-provider-tls-verify
- --enable-logging=true
- --enable-json-logging=true
- --resources=uri=/*
- --secure-cookie=false
- --verbose

Kubernetes RBAC:

- created the RBAC role name with the same name as in Keycloak

After that I’m trying to authenticate to k8s dashboard using  and get the following problem:
After secseessfull authorization, Kubernetes Dashboard sends me 401 as an Unauthorised User.